# Display number of views for a specific post for specific user in a table using django

Tags: django

i want to display number of views in a table for a specific post. I already have the data stored in db. it seems that print statement print('count', context['count_view']) is working inside get_context_data method but it is not working as expected in the template. Don't worry about the data inside the image, its actually dummy data. Anyone help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQmn3.jpg)

```
models.py
class ObjectViewed(models.Model):
    user            =       models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip_address      =       models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)
    content_type    =       models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # User, Blog, or any other models
    object_id       =       models.PositiveIntegerField() # User id, Blog id, or any other models id
    content_object  =       GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    timestamp       =       models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

views.py
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'edmin/post/postList.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering_by = ['-created']

    def get_queryset(self):
        post=Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return post

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        post=Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        c_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
        for p in post:
            context['count_view'] = ObjectViewed.objects.filter(content_type=c_type, object_id=p.id).count()
            print('count',context['count_view'])
            return context

postList.html
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.status == 'Draft' %}
                    
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                <td><a style="color:blue" href="{% url 'edmin:post_detail_view' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ post.banner_title }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.created }}</td>
                <td>{{ count_view }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.status }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'edmin:post_update_view' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></td>
              </tr>
         {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **context** allows 'dict', you can pass all of your views through context.